# too many sleep processes in mysql(typeorm, nestjs)

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

I am making a project using nestjs+typeorm(mysql).

If multiple people continue to test, a situation arises where the query is not executed.

So the table is locked, and there are too many processes whose status is `sleep` through the `show processlist` command.

After that, if I kill the process in the `sleep` state with the `kill` command, the query is executed again and the program operates normally.

There is some articles saying that don't have to worry if there are many processes in the `sleep' state through a search, but that doesn't seem to be the case for me.

Is there a way to not create a `sleep` state
If not, how to minimize the `sleep` state?

Below is a part of my `ormconfig` file.

```js
synchronize: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  migrationsRun: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  autoLoadEntities: true,
  logging: true,
  bigNumberStrings: false,
  entities: [
    __dirname + '/common/entity/**/*.{ts,js}',
    __dirname + '/common/view/**/*.{ts,js}',
  ],
  keepConnectionAlive: true,
```

The same problem occurs when the process is === `production` or !== `production`.

Thank you..!

Comment: hello @KunAguero, any update on this one? ☝️  currently I face the same problem during e2e testing, while I am not sure what the root cause is.

Comment: @JurajZovinec Not yet. I'm testing it in many ways.